# Error while installing livepatch

Tags: canonical-livepatch

Whenever I check the status I get this message

```
$ canonical-livepatch status --verbose
error:cannot locate the core snap. errmsg: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if is your case but canonical-livepatch is only instalable on 16.04 LTS.

The website says:

> The service covers standard Canonical 64-bit X86 kernels on 16.04 LTS. It dynamically monitors success rates, enabling us to reduce the risk of live kernel fixes by delivering them to a small initial group and then widening the footprint dynamically based on success.

Comment: im using 16.04 LTS. only 64 bit